# Rails: How do I query the database for all records updated at the beginning of the current day/week/month of the user's timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Right now I'm using this:

```
@today_data = Todo.where(done:true,user:current_user.email).where("updated_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)

@week_data = Todo.where(done:true,user:current_user.email).where("updated_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week)
```

But I just noticed that it's 11pm ET, and tbat these queries do not work - the `@today_data` says that I have 0 elements added today, even though I have elements that I've added this morning.

Comment: What does you schema look like? Why are you querying `updated_at` and not `created_at`?

Comment: Because of the way I'm structuring my program. It's not a mistake.

Comment: k, just wondering cause you specifically asked for "records created" in your topic

Comment: thanks, adjusted the question

Comment: The problem is that certain records aren't showing up in your query, so we need more info about those records. Can you find them through other queries? Are you sure they are not being filtered by the first `where` call? Can you post some examples of working and non-working queries in Rails console?

Comment: I'll post some examples here in a bit - my biggest concern though is whether the `Time.zone.now...` calls are used appropriately, because that's where I'm thinking the issue is coming from. Are they?

Comment: Yeah, they seem fine. If you want to debug that expression, just write `Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day` in the Rails console and see that it returns what you expected.